# If id = s001, then do

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

My variable `id` cuts the names of every subject. I have specific commands for each one, so I want to say:

```
if [[$id = s001]]; then do something. End

if [[$id = "s002"]]; then do something else. End
```

On so on.

What is the right way to do it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post some code examples of what you've already tried (case statement, if thens, etc)?

Comment: You'll want to use https://shellcheck.net/ - if not today then certainly in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to approach this is with a `case` statement:

```
case $id in
  (s001) do something 
         ;;
  (s002) do something else
         do something additional 
         ;;
  (s003) do something else entirely
         ;;
  (*)    do something unexpected 
         ;;
esac
```

There's a bit of syntax to reinforce here:

- I like to wrap the options in open- and close-parens; the close-paren is required, but I prefer the visual balance.
- The `(*)` option is the catch-all, if you want to run some commands when none of the listed options match.
- The commands for each matching option should be ended with a `;;`; there are other options for ending stanzas that are less common. I also tend to put the `;;`'s on a separate line to make it easy to tell that I've ended the stanzas appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

A case statement is pretty quick, the way Schaller said above. Otherwise if you prefer conditionals you could write something like:

```
if [[ -n "${id}" ]]; then  
  if [[ "${id}" == "s001" ]]; then 
    echo "do something" 
  elif [[ "${id}" == "s002" ]]; then 
    echo "do something else" 
  fi
fi
```

Note: the -n test is to verify that id is set so the comparisons won't error out. That's in a wrapper conditional to avoid reevaluating.